# How to create an array from a multidimensional object in php?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I would like to know if there is a built in php function for what I'm trying to do here. I'm pulling ids from a mysql db, and this is the result I'm getting.

```
print_r($result);

// output
Array
(
    [0] => SubCategory Object
        (
          [id] => 1
        )
    [1] => SubCategory Object
        (
          [id] => 5
        )
```

This is fine... pretty standard (using the Yii framework).

What I need to do is build an array of the ids. Should look like this

```
print_r($someArray);

// output
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 14
    [3] => 2
```

So is there a function built in to do this? Or do I have to loop through it like this?

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    // append to new array here
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use `array_map`, which returns a new array by applying a transformation function to each element in the starting array. So do something like:

```
$idsArray = array_map(function($value) { return $value->id; }, $arrWithSubCategoryObjects);
```

Note that the above will work in php 5.3 and up, which supports "anonymous" functions. For earlier versions, use:

```
function mapFunction($value) { return $value->id; };
$idsArray = array_map("mapFunction", $arrWithSubCategoryObjects);
```

See [array_map](http://www.php.net/array_map) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using YII to pull ids from mysql db, then you can use below code , because it will return result as you desire , then not need to process or convert it further.

```
$sql="SELECT id FROM TableName";
$result=YII::app()->db->createCommand("$sql")->queryColumn();
```